# Hide a CSS class for a specific page BUT not for the URIs / paths of that page

Tags: php, wordpress, class, hide, uri

**Background Info:**

I have a Wordpress plugin to display each user profile (front end) . When the logged in user visits their profile. The url is /profile/. When the user visits another profile the path is the same followed by their username /profile/bob1/ (for example).

Using some div classes I have created a blurred background with a another image on top to block certain Wordpress users from seeing profile information.

**The Problem:**

I would like to know how to hide these div classes **not** on their own profile page: /profile/ but all other paths from it /profile/bob1/ (for example) along with the other 'if' condition you can see below:

(As you can see I have managed to only display a div class to specific users who have the Wordpress ability to 'read'...)

```
    <div class="back"<?php if (current_user_can('read')){ echo 'style="display:none;"'; } ?>></div>
```

Thank you very much for taking a look at this! Much appreciated.

Comment: Just to make clear I need to keep the 'current_user_can' in there. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using PHP why include the profile information at all? Surely all a sharp user has to do is save the webpage locally and alter the style statement.

Answer (score 0):

From the WordPress documentation for the [Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates).

```
<?php 
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>
```

So apply the same logic.

```
<?php 
$viewother = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? true : false;
?>
```

Or you can check the user ids.

```
<?php
$style = '';
$curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
$otherauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : false;
if($otherauth && $otherauth->ID != $curauth->ID) {
    // user is viewing another profile
    $style = ' style="display:none;"';
}
?>

<div class="back"<?php echo $style; } ?>></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @slapyo . I'm a complete novice with PHP. Please could you show how your code is combined with the code I wrote above. Many thanks.